# How to set reference to an Activity array

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to have many `Activities` that When I Clicked on a `Item` of a `ListView` starts an `Activity`!
I think should use Array of `Activities` to get reference to them! But How can I do that?

I want some thing like this

```
Activity[] act=new Activity[100];

for(int i=0;i<100;i++){

act[i]=activity+i;/// my means here

    }

  list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.onItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long arg) {
      Intent intent= new Intent(this, act[position].class);
       startActivity(appInfo);
   } 
});
```

Comment: If you actually do have ~100 Activty classes, you might want to rethink how you are setting up your app/data.  Surely, you would rather just pass in some extras into an Intent to go to an Activity from the ListView item click.  Perhaps you could explain further about what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`Map<Integer,Object> activityMap;`

```
onCreate()
...
activityMap = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
```

Then iterate through your activity list and do:

`activityMap.put(position,YourActivityclass);`

And then onItemClickListener(), do :

`Intent i = new Intent(thisActivity.this, activityMap.get(position);`
Where position is the variable from onItemClickListener.

See if it helps !

Comment: No, I have many activities , I want to start an activity that relate to that item! For Example Intent intet=new Intent(this,activity[position].class); How to set reference to them in Loop

Comment: Now I see, I'd recommend you using a Map<int position, Object class> mapping the position to the activity to be started, then on click siply use the get from the Map and start the referenced activity.

Comment: I don't know about what you say! Please give me example

Comment: I don't want to put Activities in activityMap manually. I want to do it in loop!

Comment: Exactly, that's the iterate part on the answer.